# Getting exception trying to add an AD user to a group using C# / WPF

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm creating an app for my company to add a user and group to AD.

I can add the user fine, but struggling to add the user to a group.

I get the following : Exception thrown: `'System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException' in System.DirectoryServices.dll`

Please help :-D

Here is the code snippet im using to add the user to a group.

`AdAccountName` and `GroupStr` are variables already populated in prior code not shown below.

```
 try
            {
                string admin_userName = "administrator";
                string admin_password = "password";
                string LDAP = "LDAP://192.168.231.128/CN=Users,DC=home,DC=lab";
                
                DirectoryEntry dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry(LDAP + GroupStr, admin_userName, admin_password);
                dirEntry.Invoke("add", new object[] {ADAccountNameStr});
                dirEntry.CommitChanges();
                dirEntry.Close();
            }

            catch (System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException E)

            {
                //doSomething with E.Message.ToString();

            }
```

Comment: [The documentation for that exception](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryservicescomexception?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) says it contains more information about what the actual issue is, have you checked for that information? If you need help with the information you find, please post it here as an edit to the question.

Comment: Improve the exception handling code, or remove try/catch, you need to know the ExtendedError/Message properties to know what went wrong.

Comment: I don't know what value is in `GroupStr`, but seeing what the `LDAP` variable is, this doesn't look like it would come out to a valid value: `LDAP + GroupStr`

Answer (score 0):

In the end, it was because I wasnt using the whole LDAP context for the user and group.

For both the user and group I was inserting the relevant names.

Where actually it needs to be like the following

for the User name : `"CN=jdoe,CN=Users,DC=test,DC=com";`

For the group : `"LDAP://192.168.231.128/CN=IT,OU=Departments,DC=test,DC=com"`